# InvalidArgumentError using stacked LSTMs in keras

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working with a dataset in which batch items are texts represented by matrices with shape (max_sentences_per_text, max_tokens_per_sentence). It goes through an embedding layer (becoming 3d) and then a time distributed LSTM that outputs one vector for each sentence (back to 2d). Then, a second LSTM layer reads all the sentence vectors and outputs a final vector for each batch item, which can go through normal dense layers.

This is illustrated below (generated with `keras.utils.plot_model`), with 85 sentences per text and 40 tokens per sentence:

[image: Network architecture]

Here is the model code:

```
inputs = Input([num_sentences, max_sentence_size])

vocab_size, embedding_size = embeddings.shape
init = initializers.constant(embeddings)
emb_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True,
                      embeddings_initializer=init)
emb_layer.trainable = False
embedded = emb_layer(inputs)

projection_layer = Dense(lstm1_units, activation=None, use_bias=False,
                         name='projection')
projected = projection_layer(embedded)

lstm1 = LSTM(lstm1_units, name='token_lstm')
sentence_vectors = TimeDistributed(lstm1)(projected)

lstm2 = LSTM(lstm2_units, name='sentence_lstm')
final_vector = lstm2(sentence_vectors)

hidden = Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu', name='hidden')(final_vector)
scores = Dense(num_scores, activation='sigmoid', name='scorer')(hidden)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs, scores)
```

This looks fine for me, except I'm having the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/network.py", line 43, in <module>
    network.fit(x, y, validation_data=(xval, yval))
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1507, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1156, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2269, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Inputs to operation sentence_lstm/while/Select_2 of type Select must have the same size and shape.  Input 0: [32,4000] != input 1: [32,100]
     [[Node: sentence_lstm/while/Select_2 = Select[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](sentence_lstm/while/Tile, sentence_lstm/while/add_5, sentence_lstm/while/Identity_3)]]


Caused by op u'sentence_lstm/while/Select_2', defined at:
  File "src/network.py", line 37, in <module>
    args.hidden_units)
  File "src/model.py", line 51, in create_model
    final_vector = lstm2(sentence_vectors)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 262, in __call__
    return super(Recurrent, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 596, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 341, in call
    input_length=input_shape[1])
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2538, in rnn
    swap_memory=True)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2605, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2438, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2388, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2509, in _step
    new_states = [tf.where(tiled_mask_t, new_states[i], states[i]) for i in range(len(states))]
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2301, in where
    return gen_math_ops._select(condition=condition, t=x, e=y, name=name)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 2386, in _select
    name=name)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/erick/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Inputs to operation sentence_lstm/while/Select_2 of type Select must have the same size and shape.  Input 0: [32,4000] != input 1: [32,100]
     [[Node: sentence_lstm/while/Select_2 = Select[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](sentence_lstm/while/Tile, sentence_lstm/while/add_5, sentence_lstm/while/Identity_3)]]
```

The training call is `network.fit(x, y, validation_data=(xval, yval))`, with the following shapes:

```
In [89]: x.shape
Out[89]: (1000, 85, 40)

In [90]: y.shape
Out[90]: (1000, 5)

In [91]: xval.shape
Out[91]: (500, 85, 40)

In [92]: yval.shape
Out[92]: (500, 5)
```

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with the size of your input. What are you using as the input to model.fit? That's where the error is thrown.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the inputs. I edited the question with more information, showing that the problem was caused in the call to the second LSTM layer.

Answer (score 1):

Moved from question:

> UPDATE: after much searching around, I found that the problem is that TimeDistributed doesn't work with masking. I could make the model run wrapping the embedding layer call with TimeDistributed(emb_layer)(inputs), but that would disable masking for the whole model.
>
> This is a known issue with Keras but still without plans for a solution:
>
> https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4786
> https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3030

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the error.

```
final_vector = lstm2(sentence_vectors)
```

should be

```
final vector = (lstm2)(sentence_vectors)
```

Otherwise you are calling lstm2 as a function with `sentence_vectors` as arguments.

Comment: Parentheses around a single variable in Python actually don't change anything. And it is supposed to be a function call, since it is the functional Keras API. Each Layer object implements the `call()` method.